# c++/cli WebBrowser созданный в отдельном потоке ->Parent = панель формы

Tags: winforms, многопоточность, c++-cli

Нужно создать `WebBrowser` в отдельном потоке и сделать его наследуемым элементом панели, созданной в основном потоке программы (конструкторе формы).

В `Shown` формы создаю поток:

```
Thread^ ChatThread = gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart(this, &MagicBox2017::MainMenu::Chat));
    ChatThread->SetApartmentState(ApartmentState::STA);
    ChatThread->Start();
```

В MagicBox2017::MainMenu::Chat создаю браузер и хочу чтобы он появился на панели созданной в форме. Код:

```
void MagicBox2017::MainMenu::Chat(){
    WebBrowser^ br = gcnew WebBrowser();
    this->Invoke(gcnew MethodInvoker(this, &MainMenu::newBrowserParent));
    br->Location = Point(1, 1); 
    br->Dock = System::Windows::Forms::DockStyle::Fill;
    br->Size = System::Drawing::Size(255, 259);
    br->ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
    br->WebBrowserShortcutsEnabled = false;
    br->BringToFront();
    this->Controls->Add(br);
    //br->Navigate("index.html");
    chatBrowser->Navigate("http://forum.superpower2.ru/MagicBox/chat/ajax-chat.html");
}
```

Как видно, я пытаюсь получить доступ к панели главной формы через invoke.

&MainMenu::newBrowserParent код:

```
    void newBrowserParent(){
      br->Parent = p_chat; //но тут не существует br
    }
```

Вопрос: как мне передать `WebBrowser` `br` в `newBrowserParent`? Буду очень признателен всем тем, кто попытается мне помочь!

Цель: как вы поняли, браузер должен отображать чат, а когда в чате огромная куча сообщений, то программа зависает на долго. Хочу перенести загрузку в отдельный поток, для того чтобы зависал тока браузер, а программа там работала.

Comment: Обычно, перенос gui элементов в отдельный поток ничем хорошим не заканчивается.  Может просто не загружать сразу много сообщений и не использовать веббраузер?

Comment: Нельзя. Да если даже так. чат спокойно грузится в любом браузере кроме ie бкз всяких зависаний.

Comment: добавил в поток параметр мою панель, при запуске ошибка: попытка доступа не из того потока.